# Aliases not working in Unix .profile file in Terminal.app (Mac OS X 10.9)

Tags: macos, alias, profile

I cannot get aliases to work correctly in my Terminal.app. I created a ".profile" file in my home directory (/Users/my_username) using:

```
touch ~/.profile
```

Then I opened this file using TextEdit and entered the following:

```
PS1="(\!) \w: "

alias rm=“rm -i”
alias cp=“cp -i”
alias mv=“mv -i”
```

The PS1 line works fine but every time I start up a new window in the Terminal.app it reads out the following:

```
-bash: alias: -i”: not found
-bash: alias: -i”: not found
-bash: alias: -i”: not found
```

I have read it may have to to with my .bashrc file but I have no idea where to find this and was under the impression that I could get aliases to work without editing that file.

What should I try next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is with the "smart quote" `“ ”` characters; replace those with the normal quote character `"`.

Comment: That solved it! Thank you very much. I found the setting in TextEdit to turn those off. Should I turn off "smart dashes" too?

Comment: Yes, as these will also be problematic in the shell.

Comment: Thanks again. I settled for using TextMate, which has some much nicer formatting options and no issues with the symbols. Cheers!

Comment: Took me an hour to finally figure out it was the quotes themselves. Don't even know how to fix them, I just copied that 1 correct quote up there and pasted it into my aliases and everything works now. >_<